# Putting labels in slices of donut style CPTPiePlot, they don't line up right

Tags: ios, core-plot

Im trying to draw a donut pie chart on ios with core-plot, with one chart inside of another. Each slice has the same width, but the slices are color coded. I'm trying to place a colored dot in the center of each slice, but I can't figure out how to get the position of the dots correct.

I've managed to get them roughly centered using the labelOffset property of the pie chart.(currently im using a label offset of -35, determined by trial and error). But I can't mange to get them exactly centered, and in the innermost graph they can end up far enough off that they are in the wrong slice.
I have tried setting the rectAnchor property of the text layer, and the padding, but neither one seems to have any effect.

Code for creating the plots:

```
   CGFloat startAngle = [self degreesToRadians:90 + ((360 / [self.dangerRoseData numberOfSectors]) /2.0)];

    NSInteger levels = [self.dangerRoseData numberOfLevels];
    for(int i = 0; i < levels; i++){
        CGFloat radiusD =  (i + 1.0)/ levels;
        CGFloat radius =  MIN(radiusD * (graphHostingView.frame.size.height - 2 * graph.paddingLeft) / 2.8,
                              radiusD * (graphHostingView.frame.size.width - 2 * graph.paddingTop) / 2.8);

        CPTPieChart *lastPie = [plots lastObject];
        CGFloat innerRadius;
        if(lastPie != nil)
            innerRadius = lastPie.pieRadius;
        else
            innerRadius = 0;

        CPTPieChart *piePlot = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
        piePlot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        piePlot.dataSource = self;
        piePlot.delegate = self;
        piePlot.pieRadius  = radius;
        piePlot.pieInnerRadius  = innerRadius;
        piePlot.identifier      = [self.dangerRoseData nameForLevel:i];
        piePlot.borderLineStyle = lineStyle;
        piePlot.startAngle      = startAngle;
        piePlot.sliceDirection  = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
        piePlot.labelOffset = -35;//brute force trial and error
        piePlot.labelRotationRelativeToRadius = NO;//new property after 1.0

        [graph addPlot:piePlot];
        [plots addObject:piePlot];
    }
```

and for the labels:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
....

CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
textStyle.color = color;
textStyle.fontSize = 36;
CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"•" style:textStyle];
return label;
}
```

I Tried updating to the newest version of core-plot, which adds a new property to CPTPiePlot labelRotationRelativeToRadius which seems like it ought to be the answer to this problem, but it's not.  With the new version im not able to get the dots positioned anywhere close to the correct spot.

Am I missing something with positioning the labels?

Am I using totally the wrong approach to putting the dots in the slices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to give a try using images instead of text labels, and the positioning works just fine, it doesn't seem to be at all erratic like text labels.
In order to be able to fit the dots in the inner most pie I also had to change the sizes, so instead of taking up equal amounts of the total radius, the inner pie takes twice the space of the rest.
Code for generating the plots:

```
NSInteger levels = [self.dangerRoseData numberOfLevels];
    for(int i = 0; i < levels; i++){
        CPTPieChart *lastPie = [plots lastObject];
        CGFloat innerRadius;
        if(lastPie != nil)
            innerRadius = lastPie.pieRadius;
        else
            innerRadius = 0;

        CGFloat ringThickness;
        ringThickness = ( (graphHostingView.frame.size.width - 2 * graph.paddingTop) / ((levels + 1) * 2) ) * .85;
        if(i == 0)//make the inner circle twice the thickness of the rings
            ringThickness += ringThickness;

        CGFloat radius =  innerRadius + ringThickness;

        int labelOffset = -14;
        if(i == 0)
            labelOffset = -15;

        CPTPieChart *piePlot = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
        piePlot.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        piePlot.dataSource = self;
        piePlot.delegate = self;
        piePlot.pieRadius  = radius;
        piePlot.pieInnerRadius  = innerRadius;
        piePlot.identifier      = [self.dangerRoseData nameForLevel:i];
        piePlot.borderLineStyle = lineStyle;
        piePlot.startAngle      = startAngle;
        piePlot.sliceDirection  = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
        piePlot.labelOffset = labelOffset;

        [graph addPlot:piePlot];
        [plots addObject:piePlot];
    }
```

and for the labels:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
   ...

    CPTImageLayer *layer = [[CPTImageLayer alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    return layer;
}
```

Note that the CPTImageLayer is an addition to the standard core-plot to reduce the complexity of using image